# Evaluating documentation example crashes the kernel

Tags: plotting, bugs, documentation

**Save your work before attempting:** Could someone confirm what looks like a bug (definitely occurs in v10 and OSX 10.8.5):

In the [documentation for `Background`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Background.html) and under *Neat Examples*, the following snippet

```
ContourPlot3D[x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) == -1/2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
  1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> 15, MeshFunctions -> {#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2 &},
  MeshShading -> {None, Directive[Blue, Specularity[White, 50]], None,
    Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 50]]}, PlotPoints -> 35, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[.3], Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 Background -> GrayLevel[.1]]
```

is found. Evaluating it on my system, crashes my Kernel. Is it a bug or..? without any options, it evaluates fine:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) == -1/2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
      1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

and with the option `Mesh->15` Mathematica becomes unresponsive and requires a restart:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) == -1/2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
       1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh->15]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error in v9 on Windows, which is the only version I have access to at the moment.

Comment: Confirmed (**v10.0.2 & v9, OSX10.9.5**). The problem is `None` value in `MeshShading`. For example `MeshShadind->{Red,Blue,Yellow}` works but not  `MeshShadind->{Red,None,Yellow}`.

Comment: And no problem concerning your last example with `Mesh->15` (even `Mesh->50` works for me).

Comment: @SquareOne After evaluating the code once, without any `None`s in `MeshShading` as you suggested, it works with `Mesh->` anything. Odd...

Comment: Confirmed for me on OS X 10.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not acknowledged (yet) by Wolfram but appears to have been fixed on version 10.2.0.0

Comment: It also does not crash on Win7x64 MMA 10.1